# shell script to remove folder from sub directories with different names

Tags: shell

I want to remove particular directory named "classes" from all web applications with different names inside webapps folder.

For example, I want to remove folder name "classes" from /tomcat6/webapps/abc, /tomcat6/webapps/xyz, /tomcat6/webapps/xxxx etc.

Can some one please help me to make a shell script to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient one but will do the work.

First verify the directories.

```
find /tomcat6/webapps | grep "classes$"
```

If this list seems ok, then actually delete it.

```
find /tomcat6/webapps | grep "classes$" | xargs rm -Rf
```

**Please be careful with deletion as they are not undoable once done.**

Comment: When I grep it shows me all the paths where "classes" folder is located. For example, /tomcat6/webapps/abc/classes & /tomcat6/webapps/abc/WEB-INF/classes.  Now, what if I only want to remove /tomcat6/webapps/abc/classes and NOT /tomcat6/webapps/abc/WEB-INF/classes

Comment: Ok, if you want a selective delete, this command will not help. If number of such classes folder is small, I suggest you grep out the list by the first command, and then manually delete what you want to delete. If the number is too big for manual effort, you can modify the grep command to include all paths that need to be deleted i.e.

`find /tomcat6/webapps | grep -e "/a/b/c/classes$" -e "/a/d/f/classes$" | xargs rm -Rf`

This will find and delete only those that are specified, but some manual efforts are involved here too.

Comment: This is even not going to help me.

Comment: The structure is like below:

tomcat6_test/webapps/mobile1/classes
tomcat6_test/webapps/mobile1/WEB-INF/classes
tomcat6_test/webapps/mobile2/classes
tomcat6_test/webapps/mobile2/WEB-INF/classes
tomcat6_test/webapps/mobile3/classes
tomcat6_test/webapps/mobile3/WEB-INF/classes

Now, I want to remove only below:


tomcat6_test/webapps/mobile1/classes
tomcat6_test/webapps/mobile2/classes
tomcat6_test/webapps/mobile3/classes


The mobile number is too big, hence I can not do it manually.

Comment: If the directories you want to delete always have the pattern **mobile<number>/classes**, you can use the command `find /tomcat6/webapps | grep -E "mobile[0-9]+/classes$" | xargs rm -Rf`. On the other hand, if you want to exclude all directory paths with **WEB-INF** in it, you can use `find /tomcat6/webapps | grep "classes$" | grep -v "WEB_INF" | xargs rm -Rf`. If you have any pattern, it can be done by a single command. If you don't have any pattern, manual is your only option.

Comment: Thanks that worked for folders. Now, there are few files with different extentions inside each mobile folder that I want to remove like below:
/tomcat6/webapps/mobile1/abc.jsp,xyz.jsp,def.png,ghi.js
/tomcat6/webapps/mobile2/abc.jsp,xyz.jsp,def.png,ghi.js 

Also, these files are also exists on other paths of mobile1, mobile2 etc. Can u please suggest command to delete these files only from mobile instance root and not in other folders?

Comment: Not sure if there's any pattern in the files you wanted to delete. `find /tomcat6/webapps -type f | grep -E "mobile[0-9]+/[^/]*$"` will list all the files inside mobile directories (but not in the sub-directories). You can apply the file pattern on top of it and then delete them.